# PostgreSQL: INSERT Error while reading data from CSV File

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, asynchronous

I am inserting values from a CSV file into a postgresql table, the code used to work fine earlier, but now that I'm on my local machine, it refuses despite so many different attempts.

```js
const query =
        "INSERT INTO questions VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12)";
  questionData.forEach((row) => {
    questions.push(
      db.query(query, row).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
    );
  });
```

This is my insertion logic, the questionData just holds every row of the CSV file, and questions is the array of promises which I Promise.all() in the end.
[The Error I get is in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISmlS.png)

I am going crazy trying to fix this, I have changed absolutely nothing in the backend, my CSV files have only 12 rows which are the one's I'm trying to insert.
Edit:

```
What is 5+3,qwerty,mcq,chemistry,cat,cat,easy,2001,FALSE,nah,{8},"{7,2,8,3}"
What is 5+4,qwerty,mcq,maths,cat,cat,easy,2002,FALSE,nah,{9},"{7,9,5,3}"
What is 5+5,qwerty,mcq,physics,cat,cat,easy,2003,FALSE,nah,{10},"{7,2,10,3}"
What is 5+6,qwerty,mcq,chemistry,cat,cat,easy,2004,FALSE,nah,{11},"{11,2,5,3}"
What is 5+7,qwerty,mcq,maths,cat,cat,easy,2005,FALSE,nah,{12},"{7,2,12,3}"
What is 5+8,qwerty,mcq,physics,cat,cat,easy,2006,FALSE,nah,{13},"{13,2,5,3}"
What is 5+9,qwerty,mcq,chemistry,cat,cat,easy,2007,FALSE,nah,{14},"{7,14,5,3}"
What is 5+10,qwerty,mcq,maths,cat,cat,easy,2008,FALSE,nah,{15},"{7,2,15,3}"
```

[image: This is what the row has variable]
[This is my CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIMqj.png)

Comment: Open the csv in a text editor, not excel, and paste the content (just the first few lines) in your question.

Comment: I have updated it in the question. I assume it's because you want to check if the delimiters are going wrong somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I thought you were doing a COPY FROM command to populate the table, that's why I asked to see the raw file. Can you print out the value of `row` so we can see what exactly is in there for a failing command?

Comment: Sure, I updated the question, the mind boggling thing is that row has the correct 12 entries.

Comment: I wonder if the `DEFAULT` is messing it up somehow... try this instead: give it an explicit list of columns, excluding the default one (as that will get a value by default), and see if that works: `INSERT INTO questions (statement, img_path, type, subject, topic, subtopic, level, archive, is_reported, latex, answers, options) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12)`. Something else to try is to cast the array parameters, as they are supposed to be arrays but are supplied as strings: `$11::TEXT[], $12::TEXT[]`

Comment: Entirely new error this time around, ```column "answers" of relation "questions" does not exist```, although it does exist.

Comment: I copied the names from your comment on the answer. If those aren't the correct field names then just put the correct ones there.

Comment: I just completely purge my postgresql and redownloaded it and created the tables again, and that seems to have fixed it for now. Thanks for your help! I learnt a lot of new things about postgresql today.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that you're trying to push more values than the columns in your table.

i see your insert statement has a `DEFAULT` first parameter... what is that about?

If your target table has only 12 columns then you should be inserting the following

```
INSERT INTO questions VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12)
```

Comment: The target table has 13 columns the first one is just the questionid, so I set it's value to DEFAULT.  [This is the Questions Table](https://imgur.com/a/x52fXZt)

Comment: Can you paste your table DDL?

Comment: create table questions(
 qid serial, 
 statement varchar(500) not null,
 img_path varchar(255),
 type varchar(100) not null,
 subject varchar(50) not null,
 topic varchar(100) not null,
 subtopic varchar(100) not null,
 level varchar(100) not null,
 archive varchar(100),
 is_reported boolean default false,
 latex varchar(500),
 answers text[] not null,
 options text[] not null
);

Comment: The following works in my demo env
```insert into questions values(1,'What is 5+2', 'qwery', 'mcq','physics','cat','cat','easy', 2000, false, 'nah',ARRAY[7],ARRAY[7,2,5,3]);``` 
I would suggest to check if the arrays bits are encoded correctly

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that when I insert them manually running the exact same thing(just with the values) as my ```const query```, it works fine, it's only my node script that's failing